# Why is the create function in CakePHP trying to save over previous entries? Causing a duplicate entry error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I'm new to CakePHP, and I'm getting this error when I use the create function to add new rows:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0-0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Whenever I save new data using Formhelper, Profile.id gets set to 0, but there's already a row with that id. Both User.id and profile.id are set to auto-increment.

My question is: How do I save data using the next available id?

Here's the model:

```
class Profile extends AppModel {
    public $name='Profile';
    public $belongsTo='User';
}
```

Here's the add() function in the controller:

```
public function add() {
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Add Profiles');
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Profile->create();
            if ($this->Profile->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('You added a user.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add user.'));
        }
    }
```

Here's the view:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Profile');
echo $this->Form->input('firstname');
echo $this->Form->input('lastname');
echo $this->Form->input('dob', array(
        'dateFormat'=>'DMY',
        'minYear' => date('Y')- 1900,
        'maxYear' => date('Y')- 2013));
echo $this->Form->end('Save Profile');
?>
```

----edit 20 Oct 13----

Database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `profiles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` text NOT NULL,
  `lastname` text NOT NULL,
  `dob` date NOT NULL,
  `pob` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `greatest_acc` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `fav_food` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `userid` (`user_id`),
  KEY `userid_2` (`user_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `user_id_2` (`user_id`),
  KEY `user_id_3` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your database schema? What are you using as a primary key?

Update: after viewing your schema, multiple-column primary keys aren't supported in CakePHP. Use a single primary key instead, and index the second key if you need to.

Comment: Added the schema. Primary keys are 'id' and 'user_id.

Comment: Updated my answer, see above

Comment: Made user_id the primary key and indexed 'id'. Still no good.

Comment: You can't do that, read up [cake's model conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions) and make the primary key be `id`. Then it will work.

Comment: It's possible to define the primary key as user_id in your model. However, you can still only use a single column as the primary key

Comment: Thanks a lot! Got it to work after using a single primary key for both tables.